# Plotly subplots with multiple loops

Tags: python, loops, plotly, boxplot

I am trying to make plotly subplots using three loops. My problem is that the plots figures are not showing in 2x3 grid. this is my code:

```
plot_row = 2
plot_col = 3
fig = make_subplots(rows = plot_row, cols = plot_col,specs = [[{'type':'box'},{'type':'box'},{'type':'box'}],[{'type':'box'},{'type':'box'},{'type':'box'}]])

x = 0
for i in range(1,plot_row+1):
    for j in range(1,plot_col+1):
        for col in num_cat_col:
            fig.add_trace(go.Box(x=df[col],y=df['Price']),row = i,col=j)
            x = x+1
 fig.show()
```

I have tried to change the position of fig.show multiple times but still unable to get the results.
Can someone please help me.
Thank you

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? I ran this with tip dataset and it does produce 2 rows and 3 columns of box plots, although it is the same plot done 6 times

Comment: the figures are not producing in 2x3 grid. i have tried to change the fig.show() position cause thats what i thought was causing the issue but it's still not giving the desired result.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, you will need to mention what is happening... are you getting an error, are you getting different number of graphs, etc.?? ... it might have to do with data as well, because the `tips` dataset works fine with this code.

Comment: Yes, I am getting different number of graphs

Comment: @sarah444 The "fig.show()" command should be aligned all the way to the left, to occur once the loop finishes adding traces to the figure. Anywhere else within the loop, it'll print what's been added to the figure at that point and you'll get multiple printouts.